# Adding rampart.mar to classpath via Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-axis, rampart

I have been trying to find a solution for this for several days,  but with no avail.

I'm currently in the process of introducing Maven to some of my Java projects. One of them requires Axis2 and Rampart for WS Security.

I added all Axis2 and Rampart dependencies in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
        <artifactId>rampart-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
        <artifactId>rampart-policy</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
        <artifactId>rampart-trust</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
        <artifactId>rampart</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <type>mar</type>
    </dependency>
```

When I import the project in Eclipse, rampart.mar is not there, and attempting to engage the rampart module on runtime causes a failure.

However, when I use maven-dependency-plugin to copy all dependencies to a specific repository, I see that the rampart mar file is there!

This makes me believe that this is a limitation in the Eclipse m2e plugin. Anyone stumbled upon this one before? I saw several similar questions on Stackoverflow that were left unanswered.

Comment: I have a similar issue with 'addressing'.